# Using entity framework to connect to multiple similar tables in .net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, multiple-databases

A relative newcomer to .net MVC2 and the entity framework, I am working on a project which requires a single web application, (C# .net 4), to connect to multiple different databases depending on the route of access, (ie subdomain).

No problem with this in principle and all the logic is written to transform the subdomain into an entity connection and pass this through to the Entity Model.

The problem comes with the fact that the different database whilst being largely similar in structure contain 3 or 4 unique tables bespoke to that instance.

To my mind there are two ways to solve this issue, neither of which i am sure will be possible.

> 1/ Use a separate entity model for each database.
>        -Attempts down this route have through up conflicts where table/sp names are the same across differnt db's, or implicit conversion errors when I try and put the different models in different namespaces.    
>     or
>
> 2/ Overwrite the classes which refer to the changeable database objects based on the value of a base controller property.
>   -I have found nothing to suggest i can even do this.

My question is if either of theser routes can ever work in principle or if i should just give up on the EF and connect to the dtabases directlky using ADO.
Perhaps there is another way to solve this problem i haven't thought of?

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question.

I'd recommend you have a seperate EDM for each database, and add another layer (class library) on top of model (a DAL repository). This layer would be a single point of call from your controller. Then in this layer you can direct a call to a particular data context and return the result. You might also like to create common POCO's for your two databases, then this combined with the use of interfaces will give you a strong design pattern.

This way your model knows nothing about which database its connecting to - this is the job of your DAL Repository.

When you create your EDMX (in the designer), be sure to specify the "Namespace" in the properties window to be unique, before you attempt to use the data context.

Of course as a last resort (if the above wont work for you), you could create seperate assemblies for each EDM, and direct a call to a specific assembly in your DAL.

Here's how i have mine setup (im simplistic, '`Foo`'-masked terms)

I have a table called "`tblFoo`" on my `EDMX`.

```
MyApp.Model.Repository (Class Library)
  - `Foo.edmx` (`internal`, namespace `MyApp.Model.Repository`)
  - `ILinqRepository.cs` (defines methods such as `IList<Foo> GetFoo`)
  - `EntityFrameworkRepository.cs` (concrete implemenation of `ILinqRepository`)
      projects a collection of `tblFoo` into type `Foo`
MyApp.Model.Service (Class Library)
  - `IDataService.cs` (similar signatures to `ILinqRepository`)
  - `LinqDataService.cs` (concrete implementation of `ILinqRepository`)
       'greedy' constructor accepts interface `ILinqRepository`
       and invokes methods on it
    ie:


public ILinqRepository _repository
public LinqDataService(ILinqRepository repository)
{
    _repository = repository;
}

public List<Foo> GetFoo()
{
    return _repository.GetFoo();
}
MyApp.Model.Entities (Class Library)
   - POCO classes such as "`Foo`".
MyApp.WebApplication (MVC2)
```

So, i use `IOC` (StructureMap) to inject the concrete implementations of the interfaces into the `Controllers/ServiceModel.`

This way there is a 1-1 "stack-like" approach:

Controller -> Model.Service -> Model.Repository -> EDMX

In your case, you could add another `EDMX` in your `repository` (say the table is called `tblFoo2`). Then both your `repository` methods would project from `tblFoo -> Foo` or `tblFoo2 -> Foo`.

Your controllers have a reference to the POCO's, not the tables (as they are `internal`).

You can easily add more and more functionality to your repository without touching any of the other layers.

Now i know this may be overkill for your scenario (you may not like to use IoC - just invoke on concrete classes), but this is what works for me.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi  -Thanks for your thoughts...
Whilst i haven't separated my context selection to a seperate class library yet, (temporarily it is running in the control), this is essentially what i have been trying.

The problem i have is that i cannot reference my entity objects without directly including the correct namespace via the using statements.
I have been trying to do this dynamically using Reflections but have had no luck - is this even possible?

That is before I even get to the strongly typed view lol...

Comment: PS I've tried to rate yr comment as useful but am told i need to log in... - Presumably to add these comments i am logged in?
What a day!

Comment: No problems, im not on SO to to scavenge for rep points, im here to help (and more so get help!)

Have you watched Rob Conery's MVC Storefront video series (http://www.asp.net/mvc/application-development). It's probably the best video series ive seen, covers absolutely everything you need to know.

I've updated my answer with some tips.

Comment: Hi Thanks again for your help...
I have some learning to do!!! 
Assuming I can get this working will i be able to use strongly typed views?
I'm asking this as if I won't be able to, my next question would be - what am i gaining from using the EM?

Hopefully it can be done, I just can't see how at the moment as the views will need to be associated to a Model reference wont they?

All guidance very much appreciated!

Comment: Well that's another decision you need to make. Views dont need to be tied to just one object (ie IEnumerable<Foo>), i prefer to use ViewModels (basically a fancy word for packaging multiple entities into a single model object). You would have your public POCO's (Foo, Bar, etc), which all projects in your solution has access to. Then your controller can return a IEnumerable<Foo> or ViewModel -> IEnumerable<FooBar>. But yes - to get an overall picture of the benefits, suggest you take a look at RobCon's video series - it will rock your world!