# Similar Databases - Entity Model Framework

Tags: entity-framework, multiple-databases

I have two (2) SqlServerCe SP2 databases in my `DataAccess` project.

For the purposes of this explanation, let's say one database is **Company.sdf** and the other is **Private.sdf**. Both databases have the exact same structure: Same tables, same column IDs, etc.

The **Company.sdf** database contains the latest information on all products, as downloaded from our company's server to allow Engineers and Sales Personnel to access information when network connections are not available.

The **Private.sdf** database contains any projects or scenarios that Engineers and Sales Personnel have created to build a system or estimate a cost.

I started by creating an Entity Model for the **Company.sdf** database called **CompanyModel**. I finally got the Entity Model to connect to it after some difficulty (Entity Framework Noobie).

Today, I created my second Entity Model for the **Private.sdf** database called **PrivateModel**. As soon as I did this, I got multiple errors stating that each member of my `DataAccess` project already contains a definition for a similar item in the other database.

R A T S !

**How do I add Entity Models for similar databases?**

The `DataAccess` project is going to be my DAL in my n-tier approach. While searching here for answers, I read RPM1984's response in [3013146](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013146) about how a model should *know nothing about which database its connecting to - this is the job of your DAL Repository*, but I'm not sure how to best do this for my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual answer I'm looking for appears to be solved only by calling [EdmGen2](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EdmGen2). I will update everyone further.

Feel free to comment or add answers if anyone knows of a way to actually do this.

In the mean time, I'm stuck in tutorial mode.

**UPDATE:**

I've been pointed to a couple of good references by [SteveQ56 on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/IntroEntityFramework3.aspx?msg=3917779#xx3917779xx):

- [How to: Manually Configure an Entity Framework Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738546%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

and

- [How to: Manually Define an Entity Data Model (Entity Framework)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399785%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

These seem to point me in the direction I want to go without having to fall back on EdmGen2.

Answer (score 2):

If you have same structure then you don't need to create two models. You can only create one model and use different instances to connect to different database using just different connection strings.

Your context can take connection string as parameter in constructor and there you can specify two different connection strings.

Just create one model, MyModel,

```
MyModelEntities companyContext = 
    new MyModelEntities("company connection string");

MyModelEntities privateContext = 
    new MyModelEntities("private connection string");
```

Comment: I've got a connection string to each Entity Model, but each model returns a different type (**CompanyModel** or **PrivateModel**). How would a constructor be designed to create one particular Entity Model and return it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the Repository pattern. Here are a few links to a very simple examples.

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/01/20/using-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx

Comment: If you use EF as is, you are not using any level of abstraction. I believe jp2code is looking for further abstraction.